# Parsing a latitude & longitude pair from a string

Tags: elm

I have a string containing a latitude/longitude pair:

```
"50.0814253N, 14.4876106E"
```

I’d like to parse it into `Maybe (Float, Float)`. I can easily get to `[Just 50.0814253, Just 14.4876106]` or something like that, but getting the final `Maybe (Float, Float)` is quite messy. Is there a nice way to get from `List (Maybe Float)` to `Maybe (Float, Float)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have `[Just 50.0814253, Just 14.4876106]` and want `Maybe (Float, Float)`, you can use simple pattern matching with `case ... of`:

```
let list = [Just 50.0814253, Just 14.4876106]
in
case list of
  [Just a, Just b] ->
    Just (a, b)
  _ ->
    None
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, I did not realize the option to case match on lists. Thank you!